# How to snap to the adjacent view no matter how hard you scroll in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I made a Scroll View like this:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} snapToInterval={ScreenWidth} decelerationRate="fast" snapToAlignment={"center"}>
  <View style={{width:Screen}}>...</View>
  <View style={{width:Screen}}>...</View>
  <View style={{width:Screen}}>...</View>
</ScrollView>
```

but if I scroll/swipe it too fast [this](https://s9.gifyu.com/images/ezgif-7-49af049fdf2d.gif) happens (it directly goes to the last View)
but I want [this](https://s9.gifyu.com/images/ezgif-7-c26b45493c38.gif) to happen no matter how fast they swipe (it goes only to the adjacent View)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it

all I had to do was use `disableIntervalMomentum={true}`

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} snapToInterval={ScreenWidth} decelerationRate="fast" disableIntervalMomentum={true}>
  <View style={{width:Screen}}>...</View>
  <View style={{width:Screen}}>...</View>
  <View style={{width:Screen}}>...</View>
</ScrollView>
```